# AMPscript link concat not working when I send a test

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have problems with a link and I can't figure out what I'am doing wrong.

From the preview when I click on the image link I get the expected result but when I send a test I'm getting this error.

If you need more info please let me know. Thanks!

http://click.e.website.com/%%=v(@MainUrl)=%%

Bad Request - Invalid URL
HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

```
 %%[
SET @rowset = LookupRows("PF","id", "4636272")
SET @row = Row(@rowset, 1)
SET @url = Field(@row, "link")
SET @track = "&utm_source=Salesforce&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=%%emailname_%%&utm_content=trn"
SET @MainUrl= Concat(@url,@track)
SET @image = FIELD(@row, "image_link")
SET @name = FIELD(@row, "Name")
SET @price = FIELD (@row, "price")
]%%
```

Answer (score 3):

You would want to wrap your link into a RedirectTo() function
This is necessary once links contain AMPScript.

```
SET @MainUrl = RedirectTo(Concat(@url,@track))
```

Also make sure to check out Parameter Manager in Setup, this automates the utm-Parameter settings for all links in any email, which could make the coding effort obsolete for link concatenation here.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can't use inline double-percent notation for system strings in an AMPscript block.

You'll need to use the [**concat**](https://ampscript.guide/concat) and [**redirectto**](https://ampscript.guide/redirectto) functions.  I'd also check to make sure you have rows in your rowset before attempting the row & field functions.

And as always, #NoNakedPersonalizationStrings.

```
%%[

SET @rowset = LookupRows("PF","id", "4636272")

if rowcount(@rowset) > 0 then 

    SET @row = Row(@rowset, 1)
    SET @url = Field(@row, "link")
    SET @track = concat("&utm_source=Salesforce&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=", AttributeValue("emailname_"), "&utm_content=trn")
    SET @MainUrl = Concat(@url, @track)
    SET @image = FIELD(@row, "image_link")
    SET @name = FIELD(@row, "Name")
    SET @price = FIELD (@row, "price")

endif

]%%

<!-- some other HTML -->

<a href="%%=redirectto(@mainURL)=%%" alias="image link"><img src="%%=v(@image)=%%"/></a>
```